# MYSQL updating a column according to all other columns

Tags: mysql, sql-update

This is the database data.

```
Name   id  Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4 Total  Balance
Row1   1    6     1     A     Z     7       7
Row2   2    2     3     B     Z     8       1
Row3   3    9     5     B     Y     7       2
Row4   4    16    8     C     Y     7       3
```

Only the total of first row is accurate. I want to update the column "Total" and "Balance" with condition from Row2 to Row4.

This is the logic to sum the total column :

```
update Total = Col1+Col2 if Col3 = A and Col4 <>Z
OR 
Total = Col1-Col2 if Col3 = B and Col4 <>Z
OR 
Total = Col1*Col2 if Col3 = C and Col4 <>Z
```

AND also update the amount of balance, balance = previous balance + current total

Comment: Now see normalisation

Comment: You may check the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647425/update-the-total-based-on-the-previous-row-of-balance

Answer (score 1):

Your logic rewritten to valid query:

```
UPDATE tbl SET total = 
  IF(Col3 = 'A' and Col4 <> 'Z', Col1 + Col2,
  IF(Col3 = 'B' and Col4 <> 'Z', Col1 - Col2,
  IF(Col3 = 'C' and Col4 <> 'Z', Col1 * Col2, total))),
  balance = balance + total;
```

You did not write what should happens when none of those conditions is met, so in that case I left total on its previous value, but it is still added to balance.

Comment: This is totally not correct, because I want to sum up the previous balance, not to sum up current balance with current total

Comment: OK, it was not clear from what you wrote, you did not write exactly previous balance from row above, this counts with previous "value" of balance. To make what you want you need to use cycles in SQL, it can't be done with one query. I will change it for you in about hour.

Comment: Just to be sure, you wrote "Only the total of first row is accurate" ... so you want to keep total on first row, or you want to count total from cols like on all other rows? Only balance start on 0, row1 has balance 0 + total, row 2 has balance_row1 + total_row2 etc? Also what should be value of total when none of those conditions is met?

Comment: Thanks for your concern, Microproz. The most important part is balance = previous balance + current total. :)

Comment: It means that the balance of row 2 = balance of row 1 + total of row 2