# Update the total based on the previous row of balance

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the database data.

```
Name   id  Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4 Total  Balance
Row1   1    6     1     A     Z     -      - 
Row2   2    2     3     B     Z     -      - 
Row3   3    9     5     B     Y     -      - 
Row4   4    16    8     C     Y     -      -
```

I want to update the column "Total" and "Balance" from Row2 to Row4 with condition. This is the logic to sum the total column :

> update Total = Col1+Col2 if Col3 = A and Col4 <>Z
>   OR 
>   Total = Col1-Col2 if Col3 = B and Col4 <>Z
>   OR
>   Total = Col1*Col2 if Col3 = C and Col4 <>Z

AND also update the amount of balance,

> balance = previous row of balance + current row of total

Comment: use a case when in select clause to do the conditional operation.Also, I think it needs stored procedure to update the table row by row.

Comment: Would you mind to show a sample?

Comment: thanks for your concern

Comment: posted an ans with data verified. pls check if it is as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here comes a solution with assist of one user variable.

The result is verified with the full demo attached.

SQL:

```
-- data preparation for demo
create table tbl(Name char(100), id int, Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 char(20), Col4 char(20), Total int, Balance int);
insert into tbl values
('Row1',1,6,1,'A','Z',0,0),
('Row2',2,2,3,'B','Z',0,0),
('Row3',3,9,5,'B','Y',0,0),
('Row4',4,12,8,'C','Y',0,0);
SELECT * FROM tbl;

-- Query needed
SET @bal = 0;
UPDATE tbl
SET
    Total = CASE    WHEN Col3 = 'A' and Col4 <> 'Z'
                        THEN Col1+Col2
                    WHEN Col3 = 'B' and Col4 <> 'Z'
                        THEN Col1-Col2
                    WHEN Col3 = 'C' and Col4 <> 'Z'
                        THEN Col1*Col2
                    ELSE 0 END,
    Balance = (@bal:=@bal + Total);
SELECT * FROM tbl;
```

Output(as expected):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl;
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+---------+
| Name | id   | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Total | Balance |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+---------+
| Row1 |    1 |    6 |    1 | A    | Z    |     0 |       0 |
| Row2 |    2 |    2 |    3 | B    | Z    |     0 |       0 |
| Row3 |    3 |    9 |    5 | B    | Y    |     0 |       0 |
| Row4 |    4 |   12 |    8 | C    | Y    |     0 |       0 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- Query needed
mysql> SET @bal = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE tbl
    -> SET
    ->     Total = CASE    WHEN Col3 = 'A' and Col4 <> 'Z'
    ->                         THEN Col1+Col2
    ->                     WHEN Col3 = 'B' and Col4 <> 'Z'
    ->                         THEN Col1-Col2
    ->                     WHEN Col3 = 'C' and Col4 <> 'Z'
    ->                         THEN Col1*Col2
    ->                     ELSE 0 END,
    ->     Balance = (@bal:=@bal + Total);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl;
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+---------+
| Name | id   | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Total | Balance |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+---------+
| Row1 |    1 |    6 |    1 | A    | Z    |     0 |       0 |
| Row2 |    2 |    2 |    3 | B    | Z    |     0 |       0 |
| Row3 |    3 |    9 |    5 | B    | Y    |     4 |       4 |
| Row4 |    4 |   12 |    8 | C    | Y    |    96 |     100 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you Dylan. Your query is shortest and the result match my expectation! Thank you very much!

Comment: Dylan Su, you are quite excellent. I wish to make friend with you.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tableName t1 SET 
Total =  
CASE
  WHEN t1.Col3 = "A" and t1.Col4 <> "Z" THEN t1.Col1 + t1.Col2
  WHEN t1.Col3 = "B" and t1.Col4 <> "Z" THEN t1.Col1 - t1.Col2
  WHEN t1.Col3 = "C" and t1.Col4 <> "Z" THEN t1.Col1 * t1.Col2
END
Balance = 
CASE
  WHEN t1.Col3 = "A" and t1.Col4 <> "Z" THEN 
  (SELECT t2.Balance FROM tableName t2 
    WHERE t2.id = (select max(t3.id) from tableName t3 where t3.id < t1.id))
    + (t1.Col1 + t1.Col2)
  WHEN t1.Col3 = "B" and t1.Col4 <> "Z" THEN 
  (SELECT t2.Balance FROM tableName t2 
    WHERE t2.id = (select max(t3.id) from tableName t3 where t3.id < t1.id))
    + (t1.Col1 - t1.Col2)
  WHEN t1.Col3 = "C" and t1.Col4 <> "Z" THEN 
  (SELECT t2.Balance FROM tableName t2 
    WHERE t2.id = (select max(t3.id) from tableName t3 where t3.id < t1.id))
    + (t1.Col1 * t1.Col2)
END
WHERE t1.id > 1;
```

Comment: Yeah, it's easier to compare the id, but the id is random, not follow the sequence.

Comment: so next row id perhaps is not +1, but perhaps +10 or +100

Comment: @LimNeo , then what do you mean by ``previous row``

Comment: like the previous row of Row2 is Row 1

Comment: I believe we need to use rank to compare the result

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 SET @old_balance = 0;
    UPDATE tableName SET 
    Total =  
    CASE
      WHEN Col3 = 'A' and Col4 <> 'Z' THEN Col1 + Col2
      WHEN Col3 = 'B' and Col4 <> 'Z' THEN Col1 - Col2
      WHEN Col3 = 'C' and Col4 <> 'Z' THEN Col1 * Col2
    END,
    Balance = 
    CASE
      WHEN Col3 = 'A' and Col4 <> 'Z' THEN 
      @old_balance + (Col1 + Col2)
      WHEN Col3 = 'B' and Col4 <> 'Z' THEN 
      @old_balance + (Col1 - Col2)
      WHEN Col3 = 'C' and Col4 <> 'Z' THEN 
      @old_balance + (Col1 * Col2)
    END,
    @old_balance := 
    CASE
      WHEN Col3 = 'A' and Col4 <> 'Z' THEN 
      @old_balance + (Col1 + Col2)
      WHEN Col3 = 'B' and Col4 <> 'Z' THEN 
      @old_balance + (Col1 - Col2)
      WHEN Col3 = 'C' and Col4 <> 'Z' THEN 
      @old_balance + (Col1 * Col2)
    END
    WHERE t1.id > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @prev_id = 1;
UPDATE tableName SET 
Total =  
CASE
  WHEN Col3 = A and Col4 <> Z THEN Col1 + Col2
  WHEN Col3 = B and Col4 <> Z THEN Col1 - Col2
  WHEN Col3 = C and Col4 <> Z THEN Col1 * Col2
END,
Balance = 
CASE
  WHEN Col3 = A and Col4 <> Z THEN 
  (SELECT Balance FROM tableName WHERE id = @prev_id) + (Col1 + Col2)
  WHEN Col3 = B and Col4 <> Z THEN 
  (SELECT Balance FROM tableName WHERE id = @prev_id) + (Col1 - Col2)
  WHEN Col3 = C and Col4 <> Z THEN 
  (SELECT Balance FROM tableName WHERE id = @prev_id) + (Col1 * Col2)
END,
@prev_id := id

WHERE t1.id > 1;
```